# IIS 6 + ASP.NET Output Cache Not Working

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, cache

As you can see from the title, our output cache is not working. We only recently noticed but it did at one time work (verifiable with a hidden timestamp at the bottom of the page; we cache for 3600 seconds using `varybyparam="*"`). We attempted to isolate the piece of code that is causing the problem (either the page is not entering the cache, it is immediately invalidated, or the key used to cache it is unique and the cached page can't/won't be found) and it turns out that when we commend out this line:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(objCookie)
```

from a cookie-class that caching starts working perfectly!

We're not sure how long caching hasn't been working but the suspicion is that a Microsoft Windows Update slipped through QA. We have verified on an older, un-patched virtual server that output caching works perfectly (although the environment isn't 100% like our production so there's some doubt in there) and that we don't need to make any changes to our code to get it to work. Only on our production servers (Win2k3, x64 but app pools running in 32bit mode, IIS 6, .Net 2.0) do we experience this problem.

Days of googling only turned up references to output caching breaking for SharePoint after MS11-100 was applied. We've hit a brick wall and have contact Microsoft Support but was wondering if anyone in the community has run into this issue, something similar, or just has ideas about how to fix.

Comment: Uninstalling MS11-100 from our development environment seemed to fix this issue but would leave us wide open to the vulnerabilities it was meant to patch if we did the same in production. After trying a number of other ways to interact with the cookies without success, it seems we're going to be at the mercy of a Microsoft hotfix, if one exists

Comment: A Microsoft Support Rep has claimed that he was able to reproduce the behavior in a virtual environment. He reached out to the product team and confirmed that this is the intended behavior of MS11-100: if cookies are used in anyway whatsoever, output caching will be disabled/ineffective/not work.  There is not intention right now to release a hotfix as they claim this is the intended behavior. We're moving on with testing 3rd-party caching tools to circumvent what seems to me a serious design flaw

Answer (score 0):

We also experienced this issue recently, same story we never found any good article for this issue except on "http://todd-carter.com".

We have decided to stop unnecessary use of the ".AppendCookie(". Now we are checking 
if Response.Cookie already exists and the cookie value is already exists dont update the Cookie. And doing this our Output caheing start working.

Please reply if you ahve any other solution too.
pankajvtcse@gmail.com